# Setting the JRQueryExecuter property in java together with a JasperDesign object

Tags: jasper-reports

I have some code that will read a jrxml file into a JasperDesign object.

```
        design.setProperty(JRQueryExecuterFactory.QUERY_EXECUTER_FACTORY_PREFIX +    "CXS_SQL", "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRConnexysJdbcQueryExecuterFactory");
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(URI);
        design = JRXmlLoader.load(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm trying to set the QueryExecuter property for the JasperDesign object, but it doesn't seem to work. Anybody any clues on to what i'm doing wrong here ?

Regards,
Peter

Comment: I figured it out (totally missed that part while reading the documentation, sorry).

I know call a
    JRProperties.setProperty(JRQueryExecuterFactory.QUERY_EXECUTER_FACTORY_PREFIX + "CXS_SQL", "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRConnexysJdbcQueryExecuterFactory");

Before i load the design, and now it works.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: May be you should transform your comment to the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out (totally missed that part while reading the documentation, sorry). I know call a JRProperties.setProperty(JRQueryExecuterFactory.QUERY_EXECUTER_FACTORY_PREFIX + "CXS_SQL", "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRConnexysJdbcQueryExecuterFactory"); Before i load the design, and now it works.

Regards, Peter